# scp: "Host key verification failed. lost connection" when attempting to copy files from remote server to WSL

Tags: ssh, scp, openssh

I have a user at a remote server, let's call it `remote_user@remote_server`.

I also have a user on my WSL2 Ubuntu, let's call it `wsl_user@<localhost>`.

When I tried to use the command `scp -v -o StrictKeyChecking=no remote_user@remote_server:/path/to/file.txt wsl_user@<localhost>:/path/to/directory` on my host computer, it asked for the remote server's password (which successfully authenticates), but then it outputs

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

when I use `localhost` as `<localhost>`.

I have tried using both the IP address of the host computer and the IP address of the WSL2 instance, but both just hangs, and then does a `Connection timed out`.

P.S: I can ssh into both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I somehow kinda circumvented the problem using by breaking it into smaller commands, aka

```bash
scp -v remote_user@remote_server:/path/to/file.txt file.txt\
&& scp -v file.txt wsl_user@localhost:/path/to/directory \
&& rm file.txt
```